# Ajax - Send data : prompt aborted by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, post

I use Django and Ajax. I have a form, one part of this form is managed by javascript-ajax. 
When I want to pass informations to Django in POST, I have this error :

**NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: prompt aborted by user**

My code HTML :
(The url of this page is : http://localhost:8000/myfic )

```
...
<form method="POST" id="formMod" action="{% url 'myfic' %}">
...
<input type="submit" id="the_button" class="btn btn-success"  value="Validate" >
```

My code JS :

```
function send_post(){
    alert("Welcome");
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8000/myfic/",
        type : "POST",
        data : { 'the_post' : "CACAO" },
        success : function(data){
            alert("succees");
        },
        error : function(data) {
                alert("error");
            }
    });
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#the_button").click(function(){
        alert("form click !");
        send_post();
    });
});
```

The alerts displayed are : "form click !", "Welcome", "error".

Thank you for your help !

Comment: So the server returns 500?

Comment: have you tried like `url : "/myfic",`.

Comment: No error 500.  With url : "/myfic", there are the same problem

Comment: Try adding ``onsubmit="return false;"`` in the html markup.

Comment: I try : <input type="submit" id="the_button" onsubmit="return false;" class="btn btn-success" value="Validate" >. The error is always display